# HTML window object onclose or closing event

Tags: javascript, html

Is the window object onclose() or closing() event exposed in HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both onunload() and onbeforeunload() javascript events for that.

Comment: Just note that if you call a function that is declared on the closing page itself, you **must** use `onbeforeunload`. If you try to use `onunload`, the function you are calling does no longer exists...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [onUnload](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/handlers.htm#1121231) event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that lets you determine the difference between a page refresh, form submission, link clicked, or browser closed.

I am guessing that is what you are really after.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested epascarello: Events onunload or onbeforeunload you can't use directly - they do not differ between window close, page refresh, form submit, link click or url change.

The only working solution is [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#1632004)

Popup windows are problematic (bring to front, close event, blocking) and annoying - you should consider using a modal popup instead.