# how can i catch the browser has gone to exit now

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I catch that the browser has gone to exit now using javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "gone to exit" exactly? Closing the browser? Closing the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for catching the window close event try something like this:

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return confirm("Do you really want to do that?");
});
```

found here: [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score 1):

If the browser has gone to exit (exited) there is no javascript running anymore, so the answer would be no.

But I'm guessing you are looking for the `window.onbeforeunload` event.

Answer (score 0):

It only works with back, reload and tab close, not with complete browser close.

```
<html>
<body onunload="alert('Thank you for visiting');">

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `beforeunload` i posted works with complete browser close.

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery: (source: http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

And if you want native Javascript, this works on my Firefox3.6 and Chrome. I do not have any other browsers to test it on right now, but after some google-ing, it looks like it could work on IE too, but Opera might have some issues(?). You should test it for browser compatibility first.

```
window.onunload = function () {
    alert('unloading');
};
```