# Trap the window close event

Tags: javascript

I am facing the problem to logout my page. I calls the logout method from the  tag of the page like this

```
<body onbeforeunload="beforeLogout();" onUnload="logout('/ruxamod/faces/zzrucmpvhs1.xhtml?logout=t');" onclick="hideDescFrame();">
```

but I have no idea how to trap the window close button is clicked because all these methods are call when user refresh the page.

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at the following links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268866/catching-a-browser-close-event<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367232/detect-close-window-event-in-firefox

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your problem statement? Do you want to create a link on a page for logout and close the same window?

Comment: No i am not creating a link for logout I want that if user click the close button of the browser window then it should be logout the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea how to trap the window close button is clicked

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. You can't find out the reason why the document is getting unloaded.

You may be able to catch this by frequently polling from the opener document whether the window is still open.

Alternatively, you could consider using an inline dialog like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) where you can catch all events.