# unload Issue in IE 9.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using the following code to check onunload event in Jquery

$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );

It works great on FF, CHROME, but doesnt display the alert on IE9 when the window is closed. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeunload

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { alert("Bye now!"); });
```

But be careful if you need to submit a form on that page: [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score 0):

Well, try onbeforeunload (Microsoft thingy)

```
$(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function(){
    alert('Bye now!');
});
```