# jquery/jscript Prevent open multiple popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I open a popup with the click event of a hyperlink... The popup contains records from a server.

**The problem is that when I click rapidly**, there are multiple popups at once.
There is a way to prevent this? in which can open a single popup

My code:

```
$('.wrapper_form a.add').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    if(typeof(currentPopup) == 'undefined' || currentPopup.closed)
    {
        url = 'server_page.aspx';
        currentPopup = window.open(url,'server','height=500,width=800');
        if (window.focus) {currentPopup.focus()}
    }
    else
    {
        currentPopup.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your pop up only need to happen once? As in once per page load?

Comment: Should open a single instance of popup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Not the best solution but it should work.  What this code will do is protect against clicking the link a bunch of times and have it open a new instance for each click.  This code will not allow the window to be opened more than once in a 1/2 interval, of course you can change the timing.

```
var hopefullyThisIsNotInGlobalScope = false;

$('.wrapper_form a.add').click(function(e)
{
if (hopefullyThisIsNotInGlobalScope)
{
 return false;
}
    hopefullyThisIsNotInGlobalScope = true; 
    setTimeout(function () { hopefullyThisIsNotInGlobalScope = false; }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();

    if(typeof(currentPopup) == 'undefined' || currentPopup.closed)
    {
        url = 'server_page.aspx';
        currentPopup = window.open(url,'server','height=500,width=800');
        if (window.focus) {currentPopup.focus()}
    }
    else
    {
        currentPopup.focus();
    }
});
```

Assuming the popup is on the same domain as the window launching it you might be able to replace hopefullyThisIsNotInGlobalScope variable with a global var attached to the window.  You can then set that variable when the popup launches and alter it using the [browser unload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)