# Cant get alert message before closing the browser in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Here is my JS code which will be executed when close the browser or the tab. Which will makes the user status as offline before closing the browser

```
function checkBrowser(){
   function warning(){
        if($('#loginOrNot').val() == 'loggedIn'){
          setTheExpertStatusToOffline();
          cleanUpChat();
          alert("You are leaving the page");
        }
   }
   window.onbeforeunload=warning;
}
```

on documnet.ready() am calling checkBrowser() method, so that it will bind the function for browser close. Now the problem is this is `working perfectly fine in all browsers but not in Chrome`. Whats wrong in here?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event ?

Answer (score 0):

You must return a string at the end of your function. The borwser will then show a confirmation box, including your message.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxtBC/

```
function warning(){
    if(true){
      console.log('leaving');
      return "You are leaving the page";
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;​
```

Comment: Thanks Robin.. that very useful.. how can i execute the  setTheExpertStatusToOffline();
          cleanUpChat(); statements upon clicking leave page?

Comment: Just execute them before returning the string, the console.log in my example is there to demonstrate that.

Comment: if i execute them before leaving the page, and if the user clicks on the stay on page button then where can i revert those steps?

Comment: Thats a good question and might be worth to be asked on so :)