# Refreshing a page that opened a new tab/window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, new-window

I'm currently writing an internal application that handles our company's billing using MVC 3.

One of the requirements that Finance has is that a user can access a particular Client's Properties (A one-to-many relationship) through a tab control on the page. When they want to edit or delete a property, they want the Edit/Delete screen to come up in a new tab or window.

If they decide to delete the property in the new tab/window, how can I refresh the first tab/window so that they can't select the recently deleted property?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that when they are finished editing/deleting the property the tab/window automatically closes.

Comment: I wrote this little JS class to facilitate communication between tabs/windows, which might be helpful. You could easily set up a callback to refresh: https://github.com/jeremyharris/local_connection

Comment: 2 of my older questions getting a -1 at the same time? I think someone is upset at me for something. Reveal yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time to answer my own question, based on this [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#163200404) that discussed the beforeunload event.

So I hooked up the beforeunload event to do the refresh on the window's opener by doing the following script:

```
 $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
      window.opener.location.reload(true);
 })
```

Nice, clean, and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the page using a ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(loading(),1000);

function loading(){
 $("#loaddiv").load("your url");
}

})
```

Comment: I'd rather find a way to do the refresh after the tab/window closes (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

If the dialog is a browser window you can refresh the parent (the window that opened the dialog) through:

```
window.parent
```

The solution is then a javascript function in the parent that refresh the list of elements:

```
function getClientProperties(int idClient) { ajax refresh on the list }
```

When an user edit or delete a property you just call in the modal the parent function getClientProperties() passing the idClient (or a property that reference the client) through:

```
window.parent.getClientProperties(idClient)
```

If the modal is a div inside the same page, opened through jquery for example, the solution is easier because you just refresh or control the elements as the user edit or delete properties.