# how to refresh a page after submitting form in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

how to refresh a page after submitting form in word press. first i tried location.reload(); and much more example which i got from search engines but nothing worked. i tries to take the text field by id that too didn't worked. below is the code which i tried. can any one help me??

-->


  
    
      Name
      
      E-mail
      
      Phone No
      
      Address
      
      Subject
      
      Message
      
      Enter the Code here
      
      
      
      
      For information related to our Parish Contacts: Click here

--> 
//

window.history.forward(1);  function noBack()   {    window.history.forward();    }
 -->

Comment: [There's an easily locatable JavaScript method for closing a window](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+close+window). I'm downvoting this for a lack of research effort.

Comment: AM new to javascript. so trying to do with html

Comment: HTML's a markup language. It defines information, not behaviour. You can't do this with HTML. JavaScript exists to define behaviour, so that's what you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="" OnClick="window.close()">Close Window</a>
```

If you want to close it after a certain time...

add   `onLoad="setTimeout('window.close()', 5000);`

Comment: Hi HemChe,i tried with window.close but still not working.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you added the `window.close` ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try JavaScript? [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

```
<a href="blablabla" onclick="setTimeout(function(){var ww = window.open(window.location, '_self'); ww.close(); }, 1000);">
    If you click on this the window will be closed after 1000ms
</a>
```

or perhaps jQuery too? [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Comment: Hi tried this but still not working. Now am trying to use mouseover and mouseout function in the dialog box. can you help me in this?  Thanks