# calling web method on window onbeforeunload event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am working on basic ASP.net website and i want to execute server side function when user try to go away from page. For this i am using onbeforeunload event of window. I have check box on my page and when user checked this check box, i am executing sverside "checkedchange event". Issue is whenever user click on this check box my web method is also get called, which should not get called as only postback is happen, user is not leaving my page. can any one suggest me to avoid web method call when postback happen.
I wnat to execute web method only in following scenarios:
1) When user closes the browser.
2) On  click of “Find more matches” button, when user landed on search results page with no school listed.
3) when user changes the url from browser's address bar

Code on aspx page:

```
     function GetMessage() {
         var urlstring = document.URL;
         {

             PageMethods.Message( document.URL);
         }
     }

</script>


  Code on aspx.cs page

 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void Message()
{
    string x="a";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link should hold the answer you are looking for: [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#1632004)

I think the following code from that link is what you are looking for.

```
var inFormOrLink;
$('a').live('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').bind('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {
    var returnValue = undefined;
    if (! inFormOrLink) {
       //TODO: Execute some code before unload here
       //returnValue = "Message to display before the user leaves the page.";
    }
    eventObject.returnValue = returnValue;
    return returnValue;
});
```