# Execute query when client closes tab/window/browser

Tags: javascript, mysql, events

I own a Website. And I need a script that executes a MySQL query whenever the client tries to close the current tab/window/browser. The client has its own table on my MySQL database, so I need to delete that table when the client exits my site.

Any help on that?

Comment: See [Browser window close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the window.onunload event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload

You should be able to make an ajax call to run the query that you want to run from there.

Comment: I'm sorry man, i really tried, i really tried to understand that window.onunload thing, but is not working. I'm really frustrated.

I'll wait for another answer. Thank You for your help, BTW

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I wasn't.

Luckily i didn't need this anymore, found another way to do what i wanted to do. Anyway, thank You for your help bro.