# Is there a way to use jQuery to perform a certain task, only when the page is closed?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a page where I need to perform a task on unload but only when the page is closed. The problem I am having is that the unload also runs when refreshing (or postback) the page which will cause problems.

This is what I am using to test the event at the moment:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  alert( "Bye now!" );
});
```

I need to use a similar function but not when the page is refreshed or a postback has occurred.

Comment: You cannot prevent alert on page refresh event...

Comment: Just alert or anything within that function?

Comment: Anything within that function will execute on refresh or postback...

Comment: Is there anything other than the unload() that will achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: No, I dont know other way. But you can detect this using keycodes in Jquery.. You can check keycode for F5 key..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check `window.onbeforeunload` event to achieve your behavior. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event) for reference.

Comment: But Window.onbeforeunload also execute on page refresh or postback...Can you provide any code or link to avoid it on refresh/postback...