# Javascript show a designed element on browser/tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to show a designed modal or element in the browser window when a user tries to close the window, instead of a browser alert box?

I tried playing with `window.onbeforeload = function(){...}` but that was only for an alert box it seemed.

A second question is, can this browser alert box carry 3 questions and at least 2 of those questions have links to another location?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event

Comment: No, this question asks if you can design the window that shows the alert

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to style browser alert boxes or add functionality to them.

Comment: @LucasPenney Is there a way to style a box before the browser closes?  I technically just want to style a div that shows when the browser closes, instead of an alert box.  Maybe even show a div BEFORE the browser alert box?  (bad UI, but asking if it's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something in the HTML before firing an alert, but you cannot do it in lieu of that.

And no, you can't add more options to alert/prompt dialogs.

Comment: Ok, so I could show a container before the alert, then the alert will show?  Would I be able to disable the alert if they cancel the action?