# Passing id to php script from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have javascript code passing `id` to my php script in intervals of time, once the `id` is not being passed `(it means the user has closed the javascript page)`. Block in if statement should run in php script. But this scenario is not happening with me.

Code is below

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
    // set interval for 5 second
    setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({url: "test9.php?id=('1')"

            });
    }, 50000);
});

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
while(true)
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest1234.txt', 'test');
    }
    else
    {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/phptest.txt', 'test');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: should this be `$.ajax({url: "test9.php?id=1"` or do you really want the url to have `('1')`?

Comment: @ Kristoffer, i got javascript code passing `id` to my php script, once the `id` is not being passed`it mean user close javascript page` block in if statement should run in my php script. did you get my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is closed, then the page will not send any AJAX request to your server. So that condition will not arise. So it'll be only in if, the else part will not be executed at any time.

If you want, that the get request will be called when the page will be closed without if, then you can try the following:-

```
<body onbeforeunload="closePage()">
</body>
```

And then in the closePage function make the ajax request without id:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
// set interval for 5 second
setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test9.php?id=('1')"

        });
}, 50000);
});

function closePage(){
 $.ajax({url: "test9.php

 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: the `else` part is not executed when the user close the page only the `if` is executed when the page is open.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, when the page is open, the page will send the id with the AJAX call, so if part will be executed. And when the page is closed, no AJAX will be sent from the page. So there is no situation when the else part will be executed.

Comment: any idea how we can accomplish this scenario.

Comment: You mean request without id? You can modify your url to test9.php (just remove the id part) for testing only.

Comment: See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1632004/522176

Comment: @droidballoon i already sow it. thank you. but not helping what i want.

Comment: @ Indra i already removed the `id` part else is being executed while the page is open. what i want else to be executed when closing the page.

Comment: You can try <body onbeforeunload="closePage()">

And the in the closePage function in script call the POST request without id.

Comment: @ user3792355 I've added some code in my answer, you can try it. I think it'll fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The url should not have `('1')`, you need to change the following line

```
$.ajax({url: "test9.php?id=('1')"
```

to

```
$.ajax({url: "test9.php?id=1"
```

Comment: thank you. but this not solving my problem. about what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass you id by AJAX data attribute, like this.

by get request

```
    $.ajax({

        type:'get',
        url:'test9.php',
        data:{'val':value},
        success:function(data){
              }
```

by post request

```
    $.ajax({

        type:'get',
        url:'test9.php',
        data:{'val':value},
        success:function(data){
              }
```

Comment: but this can solve my problem for what i asked in my question?

Comment: yes, I think it will solve your problem. try and let me know the result.

Comment: @Indra gave the correct answer above. The else part will never get executed since no AJAX call will be made if the page if closed.

Comment: @Sunil omrey not working i closed the page nothing being executed! in my php script.

Comment: @user3792355 can you paste the updated code. So I can check. Try to print $_GET and see what you are getting.