# beforeunload event for cookie delete and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

In my webpage I want to logout a user when s/he closes the window. To capture this event I am using beforeunload event handler. But when I do close the tab the removeCookie is not called.

Here is the sample code. This is a modified code of this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384827)

```
var preventUnloadPrompt;
var messageBeforeUnload = "my message here - Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
$('a').live('click', function () {
    preventUnloadPrompt = true;
});
$('form').live('submit', function () {
    preventUnloadPrompt = true;
});
if ($("#refreshFlag").val() == 1) {
    preventUnloadPrompt = true;
};

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var rval;
    if ($("#refreshFlag").val() == 1) {
        preventUnloadPrompt = true;
    };
    if (preventUnloadPrompt) {
        return;
    } else {
        removeCookie();
        window.location = "/";
    }
    return rval;
})
```

I am using JQuery 1.5.2.

What I want is when a user refresh the page it should refresh and when the tab is closed the "removeCookie" should be called. What is it that I am doing wrong in the above code?

`UPDATE`

As the refresh was giving problem this event was dropped from the project.

Comment: Firstly, update to a jQuery version from this decade. Secondly, what makes you think you can actually stop the user from leaving your page, and reload the page instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `live()` function, which is depricate from [JQuery 1.7 Depricated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/), even though you are using older version of jquery, may be your browser is one of the latest ones, which is not alowing script execution and probably throws js error(same as my Chrome 35.0.1916.153).

All you need to do is to replace `live()` with `on()`. Below is some code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ debugger;
    var preventUnloadPrompt;
    var messageBeforeUnload = "my message here - Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
    $('a').on('click', function(){ preventUnloadPrompt = true; });
    $('form').on('submit', function(){ preventUnloadPrompt = true; });
    if ($("#refreshFlag").val() == 1) { preventUnloadPrompt = true; };
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() { debugger;
        var rval;
        if ($("#refreshFlag").val() == 1) { preventUnloadPrompt = true; };
        if(preventUnloadPrompt) {
            return;
        } else {
            removeCookie();
            window.location = "/";
        }
        return rval;
    });
});
```