# Window exit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I noticed when trawling the web for an answer that what sounded (to a relative newbie) like the easiest way of acting on a window being exited (`window.unload()`) was deprecated in a previous version of jQuery. is anyone aware of a (simple) way to do this using either JavaScript or jQuery events with the current version of jQuery?

**Edit**: by this, I mean doing something when the user exits (or tries to exit) the webpage. Sorry for any ambiguity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Comment: @Austin That has nothing to do with what OP asked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event

Comment: @epascarello ooh missed the "acting on" part. :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onbeforeunload like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Bye now!";
};
```