# Is it possible to make a Chrome app ask if user wants to quit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have developed a Chrome packaged app that can download certain video files. The videos are downloaded in the background using XHR, and multiple videos can be downloaded in parallel. For long videos, this can be a lenghty process.

If the user accidentally closes the app, all downloads will be terminated without warning.

Is it possible to have a Chrome app ask if the user really wants to quit?

Comment: Is a "Chrome app" just a regular web application? If so, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event

Comment: @Cypher No they're not. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Comment: Maybe you can pass the urls to the built-in `chrome.downloads` API so that Chrome asks before exiting about unfinished downloads?

Comment: @wOxxOm: I can't use the `chrome.downloads` API, I am using the `chrome.fileSystem` API.

Comment: Star the [Issue 30885: No way to detect when the browser is closed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885) to make your voice count. Kind of.

Comment: You're downloading them in the event page or an app window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a frameless Chrome App, add your own `close` button, and attach your custom event handler on it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that option.

Comment: Note that if you close the app by right-clicking and choosing close in the contextual menu you won't be able to catch the event. But in this case, it's not really accidental.