# Dont show dialog, when moving to next page

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a stupid question. But I have the following javascript:

```
var popit = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    if(popit == true) {
        popit = false;
        return 'Bah bah bah\nWhah whah whah'; 
    }
}
```

But it show when moving on to next page in the flow. It should only show when browser is being closed. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1632004/3382947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. With javascript you can listen if the page is ready to unload (change page, close tab, close browser), but you can't make distinct between them. Event `unload` and `beforeunload` are triggered when the page is unloaded, not differences between if its a tab closing or navigator closing.