# Detect browser close event but not on page refresh in jquery

Tags: javascript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    //action 
};
```

I have tried this link but it also get fired on page refresh.
[How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event#1632004)

Comment: page refresh manually or pragmatically?

Comment: Why is this tagged [typescript]?

Comment: Typescript tagged because I have tried this code in typescript.

Comment: Use 'event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type' to determine the type of navigation

Answer (score 0):

this is the handle on manual refresh..

```
 $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 116){
        //code here. to prevent calling window.onbeforeunload
     }
 });
```