# How to detect if parent tab is closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I stuck in the problem. I am working on website where I have main page, we can say it Parent page. And through that I am redirecting to other pages in new tab only, to them we can call as Child Page. My question is that, how I can detect on child page that the parent page tab has been closed by user?
I don't know where I can use Javacript or PHP to detecting on every child page.
I want to get the detection on real time. I mean, I do not want to execute function in every 1 minute which check for the value to detect that the parent page was closed.

Comment: I saw that here, people are busy to editing the grammatical mistake of qustion more than supporting by answers. well, i got the answer, its not clear, but it clear my point of view. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the window.onClose event in the parentwindow and send a value to the child window when this happens (set a variable in the child window). Note that the only way to get a reference to the child window is through the return value of window.open(). window.beforeunload might be more widely supported, but it also fires when you go to a different page of your website in the parent page-- this is actually more useful in some cases, especially if the user goes to a new website using the same tab. See [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event#1632004).

Comment: thank you for your answer.. yes, i knew that i can send value to child page on unload of window. But i had problem that,i will need to call a function again and again on child page to detect the value from parent page. i will use same method anyway... thank you for your answer..

Comment: @shoaib Happy to help :)