# Hi can you please tell me how to identify browser close or browser tab close event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have searched the same and i got

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function() {
     logout();
});
```

But above functions work on every request .i just want to check only browser close event usning javascript or jQuery. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event

Comment: Above link is not working for me

Comment: There is no sure way to do this with Jquery, you could use SignalR to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139970/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event-using-signalr