# trying to detect browser close event using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, browser, signalr, real-time

I have tried many methods to detect browser close event through jQuery or JavaScript. But, unfortunately, I have not been able to detect the close. The onbeforeunload and onunload methods are also not working. How do I detect the window close using SignalR?

I want to be extremely precise, and I want to trigger an event when the user initially connected to my MVC Razor view page and I would also trigger an event when they disconnected from the page as well (through a variety of events like closing the browser, unexpected shutdowns, etc.).

this is what I tried so far:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
  if (typeof event == 'undefined') 
  {
      event = window.event;
  }
  if (event) 
  {
    event.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
};

$(function () {
   $("a").not('#lnkLogOut').click(function () {
       window.onbeforeunload = null;
   });
   $(".btn").click(function () {
       window.onbeforeunload = null;
     });
  });
```

Comment: @JasonPan Thanks for your response. In which files or MVC pages should I put each of these codes?

Comment: [You can create a .js file. And import to your mvc pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H67mh.png) according your needs, you can put in specific page, not in _layout.cshtml. I use this for all page so I put here.

Comment: Thanks again and what about C# code, how to use it?

Comment: `UserDisconnected` event, I have added it in my answer.

Comment: You can try it first, and tell me it works for you or not. If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: I added a js file and imported it to my MVC page as you said, and also created a C# file with your C# codes. now what should I do to catch browser close event?

Comment: connection.onclose((error) => {
    connection.invoke("UserDisconnected");
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253442/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-behnam-faghih).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Result**

[image]

I am using asp.net core signalr and it also could be useful to you.

**Sample code**

```js
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/mainHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect({
        nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: () => {
            this._errorState$.next(true);
            return 1000;
        },
        reconnectDelay: 500 // set the reconnect delay to 500ms
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug).build();
connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 120000;

//Disable the send button until connection is established.
//document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {

    console.log(connection.connectionId);

    loadStatus("available");

}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});


var tryingToReconnect = false;

// Seems not work
connection.onreconnected(function () {
    tryingToReconnect = false;
    loadStatus("available");
    return console.log("Connection Reconnected")
});
// Seems not work
connection.onreconnecting(function (err) {
    tryingToReconnect = true;
    return console.log(err.message)
});

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        loadStatus("available");
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        loadStatus("connecting");
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};


connection.onclose((error) => {
    //console.log("ConnectId" +connection.connectionId + "Disconnected");
    //console.log(`Something went wrong: ${error}`);
    connection.invoke("UserDisconnected");
 });


// handle the beforeunload event
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    // your code here
    console.log("Before unload event");
    // notify the server that the user has disconnected
    connection.invoke("UserDisconnected");
});
```

**UserDisconnected method in javascript.**

```js
"use strict";

//Disable the send button until connection is established.
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

window.onload = function () {
    if (connection == undefined || connection == "undefined") {
        console.log("not connect to signalr server");
    } else {
        if (connection._connectionState == "Connected") {
            document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
        }
    }
}



connection.on("Chat_ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.on("UserDisconnected", function (user) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ： close browser manually`;
});



document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("Chat_SendMessageToAll", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**UserDisconnected method in Hub class.**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs
{
    //[Authorize]
    public partial class MainHub : Hub
    {
        public MainHub()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnConnectedAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// 
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            ...
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnDisconnectedAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            ...
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        
        public async Task UserDisconnected()
        {
            // your code here
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserDisconnected", Context.ConnectionId);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. Yesterday I also found an example of using chat in the SignalR repository in github (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/main/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples), and it works as it should. The only problem is that I have client code in c# (blazor), not in js