# How to implement pie graphs dynamically in .net core mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

How to implement dynamic graphs using latest Libraries in .net core mvc

How to implement graphs in .net core mvc dynamically

Answer (score 0):

There are two key points in this question, one is to use signalr, and the other is to find a suitable chart library.

In my example, I am using simulated data to dynamically refresh Pie graphs.

[image]

**Sample code**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SignalR";
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var yValues = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];
    var chart; 
    $(document).ready(function () {
              chart =  new Chart("myChart", {
                type: "pie",
                data: {
                    labels: ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"],
                    datasets: [{
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#b91d47",
                            "#00aba9",
                            "#2b5797",
                            "#e8c3b9",
                            "#1e7145"
                        ],
                    data: yValues
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: "World Wide Wine Production 2018"
                    }
                }
            });
    })
    function addData(chart, data) {
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        });
        chart.update();
    }
</script>

@*<button id="btnChat">open chat</button>*@
<br />
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="~/js/GlobalException.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
<script>
    connection.on("Notify", function (str) {
        yValues[4] += parseInt(str);
        //initPie(yValues);
        addData(chart, yValues)
    });

</script>
```

[image]

**Links**

About how to add signalr in asp.net core , [please check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144863/7687666).

And signalr also support realtime check data change [by using sqldenpendcy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159844/implementing-signalr-in-asp-net-core-web-app-(mvc))