# How to track that the user of SignalR Hub has closed a browser?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have SignalR Hub for messages in Blazor Server Side project.
In Hub i have list of users:

```
public static List<MessagesHubUser> _messagesHubUsers = new List<MessagesHubUser>();
    
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
        {
            _messagesHubUsers.RemoveAll(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UsersListChanged");
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
        }
```

But, when user just close a browser, in this case, the hub method "OnDisconnectedAsync" is not called.
How to track that the user close a browser, to update userslist and notify other users?

I tried to make a counter so that it regularly triggers a Ping method on the client and returns true if the client is connected. In the absence of a response, the user was disconnected. But the call from the counter comes from outside the hub, which makes such a solution too difficult.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe. You should use a `ConcurrentBag` or at least `lock()` before using `_messagesHubUsers`, otherwise you **will** end-up with a corrupted list - also, your approach won't work at all for multi-instance (web-farm) deployments. It's an anti-pattern to try to keep-track of SignalR connectionIds in-memory.

Comment: [Could you kindly check my test result, is it you want ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144863/7687666)