# how to track on which page people close the browser. session or log

Tags: python, html, django, spring, jsp

I created a web that helps people to understand how to make a certain food. And I am trying to gather the data which recipe most of people want to get. What I am asking is "Is there any way that I can get the information when people search a certain information and also on which page they close the browser??? should I look at session or log or else?
I really need to track on which page people close the browser.

Comment: You can track when a page closes, but not when the browser closes. Remember that some people may open more than one page of your site, so tracking page closures should be treated with care.

Comment: Several analytics platforms like Piwik or Google Analytics provide the *Exit Page* stats. Personally, I don't think it's worth the effort to code something like this when the better versions of this are already available, for free.

Answer (score 0):

make a javascript beforeunload function callback, and have that send a request to a django view to track the page they left on

I googled a question related to that:  [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)