# Capture the browser window (only) close event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  var inFormOrLink;
$('a').on('click', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').on('submit', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).on('beforeunload', function (eventObject) {
  var returnValue = undefined;
  if (!inFormOrLink) {
    returnValue = "Do you really want to close?";
  }
  if (returnValue != undefined) {
    eventObject.returnValue = returnValue;
    return returnValue;
  }
});
```

Ref : [Browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)

I tried to execute the above mentioned code in Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181
it is working properly i.e popup does not open while redirecting or submitting form,
i want to show popup only when user close the tab, sometimes browser shows the popup but sometimes tab gets closed without showing popup.
I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: @LGSon  I don't have to store any value,I just have to show a popup which will contain whishlist's data (if there is any), else tab will be closed.

Comment: In those cases where it isn’t working as you expected, have you checked what `inFormOrLink` contains at that moment?