# Calculate the time spent on the newly opened window from the parent window

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the time spend on the opened browser window from the parent window.
the newly opened window is a youtube video or any other external website which we can't do any server-side coding.

```
 function loadvideo(url , id){
  var a = window.open(url);
  a.onbeforeunload = function() {
    a.console.log("hi");
            }

 }
```

I want to trigger an event when the window is closed. I tried this. it won't trigger when closing a loaded site.

Comment: It's not clear by your description, what you want is (a) a parent window tracking how long a child window/tab stays open, or (b) you want the child window to be able to record and report how long the parent window has been open?

Comment: In any case, you'll need to use the "beforeunload" event, and date/time functions to record the moment the page was opened and the moment it's about to close. These topics will help you on that: 1.  [date/time functions](https://superuser.com/a/1292059/453576) 2. [beforeunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1632004/4645909)