# message window triggered by browser back / window close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a php developer interested in going a little more client side. I need to find a way to create some kind of dialogue when either the browser back or window close buttons are hit. Can you give me an idea of the best way to go about this.

Many thanks
Giles

Comment: I suspect this has been asked before. One similar question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460646/html-window-object-onclose-or-closing-event)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the 'onbeforeunload' event, or 'onunload'.

Some discussion [here](http://mehmoodbluffs.blogspot.com/2007/10/detecting-browser-event-closing-in.html)

For a dialog, I would look at the [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) widget from [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload.